# How to use (object references or object types) as values in a Hashmap?

Tags: java

I'm working on a programming challenge and the problem is as follows :

- there is a "Vehicle" object as the Parent class of the "Car" , "Motorcycle" , "Bus" objects, each one of those child objects has a code(id) of type char .
- there is the "Garage" object that should be filled out  with vehicles 
  objects in form of an Array-List , by passing their codes as a String to the garage constructor  .
  for example the following declaration creates a garage with 2 Motorcycles and a car and a Bus :

```
Garage garage = new Garage ("MMCB")
```

where the Motorcycles  has the Code of "M" and the Car with "C"  and the Bus with "B".

so i have created an utility class i called it "Garage Service" which is going to be the responsible for initializing the Garage and much more operations for the Garage object .

the problem is that wanted to create a Hash-map with Strings as keys and Objects type as Value , so i can use it to add for each char of the String of the garage constructor  an equivalent new Object of the that string in the hash-map  values .
i hope that i didn't describe the problem terribly  , but if anyone could  help with some approach i would be grateful .

Comment: `Map<String, SomeType> map = new HashMap<>()` should do.

Comment: Sounds overly complicated. Use a factory pattern `if (ch == "M") return new Motorcycle(); if (ch == "C") return new Car(); ...`

Comment: @John3136 actually  there much more vehicles in the problem i have just made them 3 for simplification , add to that committing a code  with such number of checking with  "if" wouldn't give me a good rating !

Comment: Why have the String at all? Why not `new Garage(bike1, bike2, car, bus)` (putting in all the Vehicle instances directly?

Comment: @Thilo maybe it a quick way to fill out the  garage  object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
import java.util.*;

public class VehicleGarageSample {

    interface Vehicle { }

    static class Bus implements Vehicle {}

    static class Car implements Vehicle {}

    static class Motorcycle implements Vehicle {}

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    static class Garage {

        private static Map<Character, Class<? extends Vehicle>> vehicleTypeReg = new HashMap<>();

        public static void registerVehicleType(Character c, Class<? extends Vehicle> type) {
            vehicleTypeReg.put(c, type);
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private Map<Class<? extends Vehicle>, List<Vehicle>> vehicleSlots = new HashMap<>();

        private Map<Class<? extends Vehicle>, Integer> vehicleLimits = new HashMap<>();

        public Garage(String chars) {
            for (char c : chars.toCharArray()) {

                Class<? extends Vehicle> vType = vehicleTypeReg.get(c);
                if (vType == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown vehicle type '" + c + "'");
                }

                // Initialize vehicleSlots
                vehicleSlots.computeIfAbsent(vType, k -> new ArrayList<>());

                // Initialize vehicleLimits
                if (vehicleLimits.containsKey(vType)) {
                    vehicleLimits.put(vType, vehicleLimits.get(vType) + 1);
                } else {
                    vehicleLimits.put(vType, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        public void parkVehicle(Vehicle v) {
            Integer limit = vehicleLimits.getOrDefault(v.getClass(), 0);
            int parked = vehicleSlots.getOrDefault(v.getClass(), Collections.emptyList()).size();

            if (parked >= limit) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No more space for " + v.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }

            vehicleSlots.get(v.getClass()).add(v);
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // How to use Garage
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Garage.registerVehicleType('B', Bus.class);
        Garage.registerVehicleType('C', Car.class);
        Garage.registerVehicleType('M', Motorcycle.class);
        // add more if you want

        Garage garage = new Garage("MMBC");
        garage.parkVehicle(new Motorcycle());
        garage.parkVehicle(new Motorcycle());
        garage.parkVehicle(new Bus());
        garage.parkVehicle(new Car());

        garage.parkVehicle(new Car());  // this fails
    }
}
```

Comment: the garage constructor that you wrote was extremely helpful , huge thanks .

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want you'll need a map to the Class (not instances) i.e. `Map<String, Class<Vehicle> >`. The actual values in the map would be the classes of the specific types (`Car`, `Motorbike`...). Then you can do something like `Vehicle c = map[theType].newInstance();` Note that this is off the top of my head, the names might be a bit off :-)

I'd still use a simple factory pattern (remember you can switch on strings these days)...

Comment: this helped me solving the thing , however it turns out that we cannot use  parent classes as references to child classes as we do with object references , so i have to define  my map like Map<String, Class<T extends Vehicle>> or simply Map<String, Class<?>>.